# angular and cron expressions

Tags: angularjs, cron, cronexpression

Im looking for some help how to parse in angular client to cron expression and how to translate a cron expression im receiving from the server.
I already saw Later.js and angular.cron-jobs but the first one is doing only one thing ( parsing from cron expression) and the second one is UI component and Im not looking for an UI component.

any suggestion?

Comment: Are saying that you want a library that can parse a String (e.g "every day at 12pm" ) to a cron expression?

Answer (score 0):

Try out [Schedule.JS](http://bunkat.github.io/schedule/index.html), probably it will help you